# Как показать сообщения определенным IP адресам на сайте

Tags: php, php7

Есть код который показывает сообщение определенному IP адресу:    `if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '93.184.216.34') die('Доступ запрещён!');`
Как сделать чтобы можно было добавлять несколько IP адресов или диапазоны адресов сразу типо 192.168.0.0/16

Comment: Ещё обратите внимание, что $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] не всегда отдаёт реальный ip клиента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Показать сообщение нескольким пользователям:

```
$userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ips = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3'];

if (in_array($userIP, $ips)) {
  exit('hello');
}
```

Для второго варианта я советую воспользоваться какой-то готовой библиотекой, так как стандартная библиотека функций не содержит подобного функционала.

Для примера, я взял эту -- https://github.com/wikimedia/ipset

```
$userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$cidr = '10.64.0.0/22';

$ipset = new Wikimedia\IPSet([
  $cidr,
]);

if ($ipset->match($userIP)) {
    exit('hello');
}
```

Comment: Так а со вторым вариантом где диапазонами, как можно добавить еще диапазонов как в варианте один?

Comment: Потом как подключить Wikimedia\IPSet и где скачать ?

Comment: Скачать здесь https://github.com/wikimedia/IPSet/releases А подключать как ?

Comment: 1) Конструктор класса IPSet принимает массив диапазонов. 2) Можно подключить библиотеку через Composer: https://packagist.org/packages/wikimedia/ip-set

Comment: У меня сайт на html сам писал и php поддерживает.  Знаю как JS библиотеки подключать, а вот с этим я что то не догоняю ? Приведите пример пожалуйста ?

Comment: Материалов о Composer много. Вот один из них - https://habr.com/sandbox/112640/